# Create New Slingshot Category

Tags: release-juno, slingshot

Slingshot category is already defined if new application installed **(Accessories, Graphics, Internet, etc)**. I want to create new category, for example **Personal** categories that contains custom apps inside. It's possible to create new category in Slingshot?

Thank you.

Comment: here are some ideas on how to create new categories: https://askubuntu.com/questions/435806/how-to-create-a-new-category-in-the-gnome-menu

Comment: Unfornately, it's didn't works :(

Comment: Try asking eOS devs: https://github.com/elementary/applications-menu/issues

Answer (score 1):

**STEP 1** : Create a new file in the launcher

```
$ sudo touch /usr/share/applications/appname.desktop
```

**STEP 2** : Edit this file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=App Name
Comment=Comment if you want
Icon=Path/icone
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
Categories=newcategorie1,newcategorie2 <===== create your categories here
```